# AngularJS V1.1 interceptor always have $q.when at the end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, return-value, interceptor, promise

In the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$http) (version 1.1) of AngularJS about interceptors, the interceptor functions all return something like this

```
return response || $q.when(response);
```

However, in my app, 'response' is always defined, so $q.when(response) is never executed.
So the question is in what situation will the 'response' be undefined and what will

```
$q.when(response) // == $q.when(null)
```

do! because response is undefined/null ?

Comment: What is `response` in your code, does it promise or some data?

Comment: it is the response from the server. In my interceptor I do things like "response.headers('someProperty)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- `$q.when(promise)` → `promise`
- `$q.when(nonPromise)` → a new `promise`, that will asynchronously resolve to the given value `nonPromise`.

Lets see what is `$q.when`:

```
$q.when = function (foreignPromise) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    foreignPromise.then(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    }, function (reason) {
        deferred.reject(reason);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

### Factory return $q.when(data)

As we can see `$q.when` receives promise or nonPromise and wrap it with.

Factory example:

```
fessmodule.factory('Data', ['$resource','$q',  function($resource, $q) {
    var data = [
        {
            "PreAlertInventory": "5.000000",
            "SharesInInventory": "3.000000",
            "TotalSharesSold": "2.000000",
            "TotalMoneySharesSold": "18.000000",
            "TotalSharesBought": "0.000000",
            "TotalShareCost": "0.000000",
            "EstimatedLosses": "0.000000"
        }
    ]; 

    var factory = {
        query: function (selectedSubject) {                             
            return $q.when(data);
        }    
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

Now we can call it from controller:

```
Data.query()
           .then(function (result) {
               $scope.data = result;                           
           }, function (result) {
               alert("Error: No data returned");
           });
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/700/)**</kbd>

### Factory returns $q.when(data) || data

From this example we return promise. So lets change it a bit:

Instead `return $q.when(data);` we will write:

```
return $q.when(data) || data;
```

It will work as well. But not vice versa.

As I understand Angular knows that controller waits from `Data` service the promise and above mentioned statement will use 1st off `$q.when(data)`.

Demo 2 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/702/)**</kbd>

### Factory returns data || $q.when(data)

Now lets call our `Data` service by this way:

```
$scope.data =  Data.query();
```

No promises, the call is sync.

Out factory seems like:

```
fessmodule.factory('Data', ['$resource','$q',  function($resource, $q) {
    var data = [
        {
            "PreAlertInventory": "5.000000",
            "SharesInInventory": "3.000000",
            "TotalSharesSold": "2.000000",
            "TotalMoneySharesSold": "18.000000",
            "TotalSharesBought": "0.000000",
            "TotalShareCost": "0.000000",
            "EstimatedLosses": "0.000000"
        }
    ]; 

    var factory = {
        query: function (selectedSubject) {                             
            return  data || $q.when(data);
        }
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

Demo 3 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/703/)**</kbd>

**My Conclusion**

The `return  data || $q.when(data)` means that our service can return single value or promise. But since we know what type of data our service returns , there is no sense in this statement. Or `data` or `promise`.

Comment: but what is $q.when(null) ? Because in the situation like 'return response || $q.when(response)' the seconds part can only be executed if response is 'false/undefined/null.

Comment: As I understand it wraps it with `$q.when` to return error promise and enter to catch

Comment: I agree. And considering the fact that the return value is actually: "return data || $.when(null);"  doesn't make any sense!

Comment: Yep, maybe before 1.5 years it was actual

Answer (score 1):

The statements:

```
return config || $q.when(config);

//AND

return response || $q.when(response);
```

Are shown in [V1.1 of the Documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$http) of interceptors. It was removed from [later versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) of the documentation. I think it was a misguided attempt to document that interceptor functions can return either a value or a promise.

The statements otherwise make no sense as `config` and `response` always have a reference.