# Angular Typescript dependency injection explicit annotation error in strict mode

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection, annotations

I am using angular 1.5 with typescript and i want to create an interceptor to insert token in the custom header and also update it from each response.

While running, i get the following exception:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($q) is not using
>   explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

```
class AuthInterceptor implements ng.IHttpInterceptor {

  $q:ng.IQService;

  static $inject = ['$q'];
  constructor($q:ng.IQService) {
    this.$q = $q;
  }

  static factory($q:ng.IQService):AuthInterceptor {
    return new AuthInterceptor($q);
  }


  request = (config:ng.IRequestConfig):ng.IRequestConfig => {
   // config.headers = config.headers || {};
   console.info('Request config md', config);
   // config.headers['token'] = 'test token';

   return config;
 };

  response = <T>(response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>):ng.IPromise<T> => {
    console.info('Response:', response);

// modify response

  return this.$q.when(response);
};
```

}

```
let httpConfig = ($httpProvider:ng.IHttpProvider) => {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(AuthInterceptor.factory);
};

angular.module('app').config(httpConfig);
```

Do you have any idea, how i can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. this is simplest interceptor for every request

```
app.factory('myInterceptor', function() {  
        var requestInterceptor = {
            request: function(config) {
                return config;
            }
        };
        return requestInterceptor;
    });

    app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I need $q for response interception. Also i need to use typescript.

Comment: @Jhankar you can use $q also there

Comment: If I use $q as dependency injection, I get the mentioned error due to using strict mode.

Comment: @Jhankar refer this link. you will understand. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770889/angularjs-interceptor-always-have-q-when-at-the-end]