# How to throw error from 'reponse' function of $httpProvider interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I am making a http interceptor in angular and I want to make throw error from `response` of  `$httpProvider` interceptor.

As per the documentation:

> `response`: interceptors get called with http response object. The function is free to modify the response object or create a new one. The function needs to return the response object directly, or as a promise containing the response or a new response object.
>
> `responseError`: interceptor gets called **when a previous interceptor
>   threw an error** or resolved with a rejection.

I want to do the bold part in above quote so that a response with status 200 (I've a condition there) is routed to `responseError` where I will handle the error.
Not returning a response throws following error:

```
Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

I do not want to return the response but want to pass it to next handler i.e `responseError`.

How can I do that?
I hope I made it clear.
Thanks.

Update (Code Below):

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    interceptor.$inject = ['$q', '$rootScope'];
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);

    function interceptor($q, $rootScope) {
        return {
            response: response,
            responseError: responseError
        };

        function response(response) {
            if (response.data.rs == "F") {
                // I want to route it responseError -->
            } else {
                return response;
            }
        }

        function responseError(response) {
            // I want to handle that error here
        }
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Show your code mate

Comment: @Satpal pls check

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
return $q.reject(response);
```

Also make sure you return: (Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19771163/2905527))

`return response || $q.when(response);`

instead of:

```
return response;
```

Comment: I tried this `return $q.reject(response);` but the control doesn't go to `responseError` .. :/